# lost data after updating to iOS 6.0.1

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I have been getting data lost reports from users as they have upgraded to iOS 6.0.1  I launched a new version of our app that was using Cordova 2.1 shortly before ios 6.0.1 release. After the release I began to get reports of data lost.  Is there another iOS 5.0 data storage issue with phonegap and iOS 6.0.1?  Our app and users depend on data being retrievable.  Another data loss like we had with iOS 5 will be devastating.  I have rebuilt the app using cordova 2.2 and tested with an upgrade to ios 6.0.1.  Data was lost once I did a hard stop on the app. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing you've run afoul of the "[Data Storage Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/)" stuff.  It was introduced in 5 but was changed in 6, and data is much more likely to go "poof" if not properly marked.